# Turn off CnPack Ctrl + U feature

Tags: delphi, ide

I recently started using *CnPack* because I like how it displays nested code (and the colors!). However, I have found myself turning off most of the other features as I find them.

One feature that I can't seem to turn off is the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> to see the unit list. Under the CnPack menu >> Project Enhancements >> List Units. This could be useful for some, but I much prefer *MMX* <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> feature as it can add units if you need it to.

I've looked under the settings (in multiple places) and haven't seen it. Anybody know how to turn this off?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. [Go to menu **CnPack / Options...**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sIjB3.png)
2. [Select **Project Extension Wizard**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lKF2N.png)
3. [Click **Settings** button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PiF9k.png)
4. [Select **List units...** item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNPX0.png)
5. [Focus **ShortCut** edit and press **Backspace** key](https://i.stack.imgur.com/06ulc.png)
6. [Save the settings with the **OK** button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZcNP.png)

Comment: Thanks for the help! Now how am I going to survive when someone answers my next question without pictures??